# CSS transform not working in safari

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to move a search box widget on a WordPress page by using translate (since it be put there by default). The code below works on all of the major browsers except Safari both the desktop and mobile versions. The code is below:

```css
 input#s {

    -ms-transform: translateY (85px);
-webkit-transform: translateY (85px);
-moz-transform: translateY (85px);
-o-transform: translateY (85px);
transform: translateY(85px);
z-index: 1000;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;

}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you please post the rest of your css and html code?  Or better yet please make a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you have spaces after `translateY` on all of them but the non-prefixed? That's what I'd venture the issue is.

It's reading the `translateY` but you have "no value" attached to it due to the spaces.

Comment: there isn't a particular reason for the spaces. I have now removed the spaces and it works. Thanks.